# Trying to implement a word search in C

Tags: c

As the title says, I'm trying to make a word search in C. However, when I run what I have, I'm getting an aborted(core dumped) message.

My code:

```
void lefttoright(int rowcol, char **matrix, char* find){

    int i, j, k, q, len, count = 0;
    len = strlen(find);

    for (i = 0; i < rowcol; i++){
            for (j = 0; j < rowcol; j++){
                    if (matrix[i][j] == find[0]){
                            char* correct = malloc(sizeof(char) * 20);

                            for (q = j; q < rowcol; q++){
                                    for (k = 0; k < len; k++){
                                            if (matrix[i][q] == find[k]){
                                                    correct[k] = matrix[i][q];
                                            }
                                    }
                            if (strcmp(correct, find) == 0){
                                    count++;
                                    printf("%s\n", correct);
                                    printf("%d\n", count);
                            }
                            }
                            free(correct);
                    }
                    else continue;
            }
    }
    printf("%d", count);
}
```

.

```
if (strcmp(correct, find) == 0){
         count++;
         printf("%s\n", correct);
         printf("%d\n", count);
}
```

prints

```
bagel
1
bagel
2
bagel
3
bagel
4
bagel
5
bagel
6
bagel
7
bagel
8
bagel
9
bagel
10
bagel
11
bagel
12
bagel
13
Aborted (core dumped)
```

What is making it abort? Also, what do I need to do differently to make count == 1 (the word only appears once)?

My entire program if needed:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "scanner.h"
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

char** matrixMaker(int argc, char **argv);
void displayMatrix(int rowcol, char **matrix);
void lefttoright(int rowcol, char **matrix, char* find);

int main(int argc, char **argv){

    FILE *fp = fopen(argv[2], "r");

    int rowcol = atoi(argv[1]);
    int a, i = 0, j;
    unsigned char cha;
    char **matrix;
    matrix = malloc( sizeof(char *) * rowcol);

    for (a=0; a<20; a++)
            matrix[a] = malloc( sizeof(char) * rowcol);

    for (i = 0; i < rowcol; i++){
            for (j = 0; j < rowcol; j++){
                    cha = tolower((unsigned char)readChar(fp));
                    matrix[i][j] = cha;
            }
    }

    char* find = malloc(sizeof(char) * 20);

    displayMatrix(rowcol, matrix);

    printf("Enter a word to find in the puzzle : \n");
    scanf("%s", find);

    while(find[i]){
            putchar(tolower((unsigned char)find[i]));
            i++;
    }

    lefttoright(rowcol, matrix, find);

    free(matrix);

    return 0;
}

void displayMatrix(int rowcol, char **matrix){

    int r,c;
    for (r = 0; r < rowcol; ++r){
            for (c = 0; c < rowcol; ++c){
                    printf("%c",matrix[r][c]);
            }
            printf("\n");
    }
}

void lefttoright(int rowcol, char **matrix, char* find){

    int i, j, k, q, len, count = 0;
    len = strlen(find);

    for (i = 0; i < rowcol; i++){
            for (j = 0; j < rowcol; j++){
                    if (matrix[i][j] == find[0]){
                            char* correct = malloc(sizeof(char) * 20);

                            for (q = j; q < rowcol; q++){
                                    for (k = 0; k < len; k++){
                                            if (matrix[i][q] == find[k]){
                                                    correct[k] = matrix[i][q];
                                            }
                                    }
                            if (strcmp(correct, find) == 0){
                                    count++;
                                    printf("%s\n", correct);
                                    printf("%d\n", count);
                            }
                            }
                            free(correct);
                    }
                    else continue;
            }
    }
printf("%d", count);
}
```

Comment: Instead of providing a solution, it's better if you debug the program.  Please let us know which compiler and operating system you are using so we can tell you how to debug.  For example, if you are on Solaris and using native compiler, you may use: dbx myprogram core  ; However if you are on Windows in Visual Studio, you can just run the program by pressing F5 (it will run with debugger).  The debugger will show you where the problem is, and you'll be able to inspect variables at time of crash and figure out the problem.

Comment: I'm using GCC. I've looked up how to debug it but it didn't make much sense to me. I'll give it a try.

Comment: I don't see how your code would produce `bagel` even once. What sort of input are you giving it?

Comment: You need to null terminate the `correct` string.

Comment: Jongware - I type in bagel when prompted for a word to search for. Lundin - what's the command for that?

Comment: If you end up debugging the problem, go through a gdb tutorial, for example here's simple one I found: http://cs.baylor.edu/~donahoo/tools/gdb/tutorial.html   Basically you end up building a program with debugging enabled by specifying '-g' flag, as follows: gcc -g myfile.c -o myprogram   Then you run debugger: gdb myprogram From this point on you'll use commands such as: run - this will start the program, up - this will go up the stack, etc. I'd look at some tutorials and make a list of commands you're likely to use (up/down/print/list/break/continue).

Comment: With what arguments do you run the program?